# how to use java in php in monitoring files in linux

Tags: java, php, linux

I have program in linux which creates/modify a file when it detects a new connected socket. It logs the ip in that file and deletes it when the client is disconnected or disconnects..

In php i know inotify but it's blocking and refreshes unlike java it doesn't.. How can i do this with java and php so i can monitor a files in linux and update the website that a file in linux has been modified?

Thank you..

e.g in php..

```
<?php

$fd = inotify_init();

$watch_descriptor = inotify_add_watch($fd, '/tmp/devfile.txt', IN_MODIFY);

touch('/tmp/devfile.txt');

while(true){
$events = inotify_read($fd);

$contents =file_get_contents('/tmp/devfile.txt');

echo $contents;
}

$read = array($fd);
$write = null;
$except = null;

stream_select($read,$write,$except,0);


stream_set_blocking($fd, 0);

inotify_read($fd); 

$queue_len = inotify_queue_len($fd);

inotify_rm_watch($fd, $watch_descriptor);


fclose($fd);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "java and php", but if what you are looking for is a pure-java way to be notified of changes to the file, then you can use java.nio.file.Path and the WatchService api.

[Here is an explanation from the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) of how it works.

Comment: Thanks does this work without refreshing the browser?.. I'm new in java and i need to work on data where i don't need to refresh to get new data. thanks again.

Comment: @demic0de - What we're talking about here has nothing to do with web browsers (but then, neither does your php code, as far as I can tell). If you want to get your notifications from the server to the client's browser, and want to do so without refreshing the browser, have a look at WebSockets.

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 supports inotify-like file notifications. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) for a tutorial.

Perhaps you could find or write a C program that you could use from PHP?

Comment: "Perhaps you could find or write a C program that you could use from PHP?"  --- What do  you mean by that?.. c program that will communicate with php?

Comment: Yes, I did something like that. Although I don't really know PHP's capabilities. Can you call C functions from PHP? If so then just do that.